# Which Interface's (extending CrudRepository) delete method was triggered using spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

I am calling `userRepo.deleteById(1)` from my service layer and using spring AOP I want to log the Interface name whenever any `deleteById` is called so that I can track which interface's `deleteById` was triggered. I want an output which can give me a clue of the interface name.

`joinPoint.getSignature()` returns the generic name i.e. void `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.deleteById(Object)` and but I want to see `UserRepository` or any repository name whose `deleteById` was called.

Comment: That is the one that gets called, as that is where it is defined in. Else get the class of the target instead of getting the method signature from the joinpoint.

Comment: The get target returns org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@6521684f but I want something like com.yash.arci.repository.UserRepository

Answer (score 2):

Will this help ?

```
@Before("execution(* org.sec3.jpa.bean.*.deleteById(*)) && target(bean)")
public void getRepositoryName(JoinPoint jp , Object bean ) throws Exception {
    Advised advised = (Advised) bean;
    for(Class<?> clazz : advised.getProxiedInterfaces())
    System.out.println(clazz);
}
```

prints

```
interface org.sec3.jpa.bean.TestEmployeeRepository
interface org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
interface org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy
```

TestEmployeeRepository is as follows

```
package org.sec3.jpa.bean;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TestEmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaEmployee, Long> {

}
```

More details :  [Manipulating Advised Objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api-advised)

Comment: For me it prints
    execution(public abstract java.util.Optional 
    org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findById(java.lang.Object))
and execution(public abstract void org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.deleteById(java.lang.Object))

Comment: modified the answer