# Log the actual repository class instead of CrudRepository of JPARepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

Pre note: Really surprised and annoyed that why cant I find this simple thing.

```
public Object interceptMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  joinPoint.getTarget(); //returns SimpleJpaRepository
  joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(); //Returns CrudRepository
}
```

How do I get the actual repository name ?

Comment: I answered a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915717/which-interfaces-extending-crudrepository-delete-method-was-triggered-using-s/58939082#58939082

Comment: @R.G You, the real MVP. !!!

Comment: Glad that I could help!!. Now I am confused if I should retain my answer here or not.

Comment: marked as accepted! surprising that , your post did not catch my eyes and I literally dissected SO yesterday looking for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of getting the actual repository name

```
@Before("execution(* org.sec3.jpa.bean.*.deleteById(*)) && target(bean)")
public void getRepositoryName(JoinPoint jp , Object bean ) throws Exception {
    Advised advised = (Advised) bean;
    for(Class<?> clazz : advised.getProxiedInterfaces())
    System.out.println(clazz);
}
```

will print

```
interface org.sec3.jpa.bean.TestEmployeeRepository
interface org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
interface org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy
```

TestEmployeeRepository

```
package org.sec3.jpa.bean;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TestEmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaEmployee, Long> {

}
```

My answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915717/which-interfaces-extending-crudrepository-delete-method-was-triggered-using-s/58939082#58939082)