# Spring AOP Pointcut for Spring Data Rest Controller (EndPoint)

Tags: spring-data, spring-aop, spring-data-rest

I would like to do something on every api call to my spring boot app. I use Spring AOP to achieve this. Using:

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controller() {
}

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
public void restController() {
}

@After("(controller() || restController())")
public void loggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
   // TODO: do something
}
```

Using that I can get all the event when API is being called. However, I am also using spring rest data for crud mechanism that automatically generate API end point, for example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The question is, can I create a point cut for every API end point that is generated by spring rest data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following pointcut will target all the RESTful endpoint calls made at `"/users"`

Considering the package of `UserRepository` is `rg.so.example.datarest`

```
@Pointcut("execution(* rg.so.example.datarest.UserRepository.*(..))")
public void dataRest() {
}
```

A more generic pointcut to target all the Repository implementations in a package `rg.so.example.datarest` would be

```
@Pointcut("execution(* rg.so.example.datarest..*(..))")
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment since I just found that's not the problem (I did not know that you have replied already, sorry).
The real problem is this line:  
`final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`  
I need to get the user IP so that I need to that line.

Comment: No, this problem happened after I added the springDataRestController() pointcut from your suggestion.

Comment: got it . I deleted my comments as well. I assume your issue is resolved now

Comment: the error message is:  
`No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
`

Comment: I found the solution for this problem. So, on setup there is a call to a method "configureRepositoryRestConfiguration" and this does not have RequestContext. So, it's solved by checking the method name and stop the process if it's equal to `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration`, like:  
`"configureRepositoryRestConfiguration".equals(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()`

Comment: Good to know you found the solution.Not sure about `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` . I didnt get that issue when testing the solution. Is that a custom method or something from spring framework ?

Comment: I don't know where the `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` come from, but I am not create such method.

I still have a problem :-(  
when I use `@Pointcut("execution(* rg.so.example.datarest..*(..))")` the `joinPoint.getSignature().getName()` return something like `findAll` but I could not find from which repo does this `findAll` come from. Do you know how to identify from which repo does it come from?

Comment: I had answered this earlier. Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59199460/4214241